# How to make method POST in grails?

Tags: java, rest, post, grails, groovy

I have created one method and calling from Postman client (POST) call , but its not recognized it , i have no param in URL i am passing data to body, but still its considering as GET call.
Any help appreciated
i have define below code on controller action ,

```
@RestApiMethod(verb = RestApiVerb.POST)
```

Also tried as per [Grails Allowedmethods](https://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html) but its not working. 
My UrlMapping so far,

```
 "/api/guest/v1/$aController/$aAction?(.$format)?"{
        controller ={ "${params.aController}Api" }
        action = { "${params.aController}_${params.aAction.replaceAll("-","_")}" }
        view = null
    }
```

I am using Grails 2.5.1 version.

What other changes i have to do to make my method as POST ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't mention anything about your environment (grails version, url map, etc) its kinda hard to see what's causing the issue with your application.

The `@RestApiMethod(verb = RestApiVerb.POST)` annotation does not have anything to do with how grails will process the request, it is even not part of the grails framework. The only reference that I can found that it is from an very old rest-api-doc plugin from five years ago.

Try adding a new entry of the url path to the `UrlMappings` file like:

`/my_path/my_action  controller: 'myController', action: 'myAction', method: 'POST'`

Update:

Can't see the point on why would you need to do something like that in your UrlMapping. There are two buit-in variables on a UrlMapping artefact: `controller` and `action` so you do not need to do anything else to get them recognized.

UrlMapping:

```
"/api/guest/v1/${controller}/${action}?(.$format)?" {
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
package rest.api.test

import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic
import grails.converters.JSON

@GrailsCompileStatic
class RestApiController {

    static allowedMethods = [index: 'GET', show: 'GET', save: 'POST',
                             update: 'PUT', delete: 'DELETE']

    def index() {
        renderJson()
    }

    def show() {
        renderJson()
    }

    def save() {
        renderJson()
    }

    def update() {
        renderJson()
    }

    def delete() {
        renderJson()
    }

    private void renderJson() {
        log.info("Receive data: ${params}")
        render([controller: controllerName, action: actionName, uri: actionUri] as JSON)
    }

}
```

`controller` will be your controller name, and `action` will be the method name inside that controller. So if you have `RestApiController` and method `save` the path would be `/api/guest/v1/restApi/save`.

The `allowedMethods` will ensure that the method (action) will only responds to the proper HTTP method, for example in the controller code above if you are trying to make GET to `/api/guest/v1/restApi/save` you will get HTTP 405 (method not allowed).

More details can be found on the [grails documentation](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings).

Comment: Updating my question, Sorry for that.

Comment: Any reason why would you need to use this `$aController/$aAction?(.$format)?` in your UrlMappings?

Comment: May be because i am extending my controller to RestFulController.

Comment: I tried as per your explanation but seems its not working.

Comment: If adding `allowedMethods` still does not have any affect on your controller then something is definitely amiss. You would have to investigate other factor in your application and debug the controller using tools like postman or curl or write a unit test for it. I've tested the code above on a new grails project without any issue.

Comment: Well then let me try to create new app and check.